# How to pass Data from Redis to Next Js pages

Tags: reactjs, express, redis, next.js

I'm using express as a middleware, wanted to know how to pass the data from Redis DB to my pages from inside the express middleware and if there is a way to set them in a context provider only once on the initial load and not pass the data again and again for each page.

Comment: yeah, it looks like my fav issue is related https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/4810